# Can I use Oracle GoldenGate with Autonomous Database on both of Public and Private endpoints?

Tags: oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

It is possible to use Goldengate with Autonomous Database but I'm not sure whether there are any restrictions on the ADB endpoint type for using Goldengate. Can it can be used for both Public and Private endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle GoldenGate connects to Oracle databases using SQL*Net.  You need to be able to establish a SQL*Net connection from the server where OGG is running to the Oracle database. As long as the VM running GoldenGate is able to access ADB, it should be good.

You can establish a SQL*Net connection with either public or private endpoints.